# JMeter, threads using dynamic incremented value

Tags: jmeter

I have created a JMeter functional test that essentially:

1. creates a user;
2. logs in with the user;
3. deletes the user.

Now, I need to be able to thread this, and dynamically generate a username with a default prefix and a numerically incremented suffix (ie TestUser_1, TestUser_2, ... etc).

I used the counter, and things were working fine until I really punched up the number of threads/loops. When I did this, I was getting a conflict with the counter. Some threads were trying to read the counter, but the counter had already been incremented by another thread. This resulted in trying to delete a thread that was just created, then trying to log in with a thread that was just deleted.

The project is set up like this:

```
Test Plan
    Thread group
        Counter
        User Defined Variables
        Samplers
```

I was hoping to solve this problem by using the counter to append a number to the user defined variables upon thread execution, but the counter cannot be accessed in the user defined variables.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 4):

I've used the following scheme successfully with any amount of test users:

**1.** Generate using beanshell-script (in [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) e.g.) csv-file with test-user details, for example:

```
testUserName001,testPwd001
testUserName002,testPwd002
. . .
testUserName00N,testPwd00N
```

with the amount of entries you need for the test-run.
This is done once per "N users test-run", in separate Thread Group, in [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) or maybe even in separate jmx-script... makes no difference.

You can please find working beanshell-code below.

**2.** Create your test users IN TEST APPLICATION using previously created users-list.
If you don't need create in application you may skip this.

```
    Thread Group
    Number of Threads = 1   
    Loop Count = 1
        . . .
        While Controller
        Condition = ${__javaScript("${newUserName}"!="",)}  // this will repeat until EOF
            CSV Data Set Config
            Filename = ${__property(user.dir)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}${__P(users-list,)}    // path to generated users-list
            Variable Names = newUserName,newUserPwd    // these are test-users details read from file into pointed variables
            Delimiter = '
            Recycle on EOF? = False
            Stop thread on EOF? = True
            Sharing Mode = Current thread group

            [CREATE TEST USERS LOGIC HERE]  // here are actions to create separate user in application
                . . .
```

**3.** Perform multi-user logic.
Schema like the given above one but Thread Group executed not for 1 but for N threads.

```
    Thread Group
    Number of Threads = ${__P(usersCount,)}    // set number of users you need to test
    Ramp-Up Period = ${__P(rampUpPeriod,)}  
    Loop Count = X
        . . .
        While Controller
        Condition = ${__javaScript("${newUserName}"!="",)}  // this will repeat until EOF
            CSV Data Set Config
            Filename = ${__property(user.dir)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}${__P(users-list,)}    // path to generated users-list
            Variable Names = newUserName,newUserPwd    // these are test-users details read from file into pointed variables
            Delimiter = '
            Recycle on EOF? = False
            Stop thread on EOF? = True
            Sharing Mode = Current thread group

            [TEST LOGIC HERE]  // here are test actions
                . . .
```

The key idea is in using Thread Group + While Controller + CSV Data Set Config combination:

3.1. CSV Data Set Config reads details for each the test users from generated file:
. . . a. only once - because of "Stop thread on EOF? = True";
. . . b. doesn't block file for further access (in another thread groups, e.g., if there are any) - because of "Sharing Mode = Current thread group";
. . . c. pointed variables - "Variable Names = newUserName,newUserPwd" - you will use in further test-actions;
3.2. While Controller forces CSV Data Set Config to read all the entries from generated file - because of defined condition (until the EOF).
3.3. Thread Group will start all the threads with defined ramp-up - or simultaneously if ramp-up = 0.

You can take here template script for described schema: [multiuser.jmx](http://www.filehat.com/en/file/27316/multiuser-jmx.html).

Beanshell script to generate test-users details looks like below and takes the following args:
 - test-users count
 - test-user name template ("TestUser_" in your case)
 - test-user name format (e.g. 0 - to get TestUser_1, 00 - to get TestUser_01, 000- for TestUser_001, etc... you can simply hardcode this orexclude at all)
 - name of generated file.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

int count = Integer.valueOf(params[0]);
String testName = params[1];
String nameFormat = params[2];
String usersList = params[3];

StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

try {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(nameFormat);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + usersList);

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        String s = formatter.format(i);
        String testUser = testName + s;
        contents.append(testUser).append(",").append(testUser);

        if (i < count) {
            contents.append("\n");
        }
    }

    byte [] buffer = contents.toString().getBytes();    

    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    IsSuccess = false;
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (Throwable thex) {
    System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
```

All together it will look like:

[image]

Sorry if answer is too overloaded.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The "User Defined Variables" config element does not pick up the reference variable from the "Counter" config element. I think this is a bug in JMeter. I have verified this behavior in version 3.2.
I added a "BeanShell Sampler" element to work around the issue.

Notice that the reference name of the "Counter" element is `INDEX` 
[image: Counter]

The `RUN_FOLDER` variable gets set to a combination of the `TESTS_FOLDER` variable and the `INDEX` variable in the "BeanShell Sampler"
[image: BeanShell]

The "Debug Sampler" simply gathers a snapshot of the variables so I can see them in the "View Results Tree" listener element. Notice how the `RUN_FOLDER` variable has the `INDEX` variable value (5 in this case) appended.
[image]