# Difference between sharing modes "All threads" and "Current thread group" in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

What is the actual difference between Sharing mode "All threads" and "Current thread group" in Jmeter?
Can anyone explain in detail?

I have one liner definition but i am not able to understand it properly.

Thanks,
Rishil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, as per [reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config):

```
 • All threads - (the default) the file is shared between all the threads. 
 • Current thread group - each file is opened once for each thread group in which the element appears
```

So in case of "All threads" if you have in your script more than 1 CSV Data Set Config elements that refer the same file the next CSV Data Set Config element will **CONTINUE READING** from previously opened file (i.e. in prevoius CSV Data Set Config element), and in case of "Current thread group" each subsequent CSV Data Set Config element will **REOPEN** your file.

Please look onto example below:

[image]

In this case each CSV Data Set Config element:

 • uses the same csv-file;

 • reads file once and till the EOF;

 • reads file from beginning: file is re-opened each time because of Sharing Mode = Current thread group.

If in this case change Sharing Mode to "All threads" WITHOUT any other changes the 2nd (TG-04) and the 3rd (TG-05) CSV Data Set Config elements will read nothing because the csv-file will remain open after TG-03 and file cursor will point to end of file.

Implementation details find in [CSVDataSet class description](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/CSVDataSet.html):

> The class uses the FileServer alias mechanism to provide the different
>   share modes.  For all threads, the file alias is set to the file name.
>   Otherwise, a suffix is appended to the filename to make it unique
>   within the required context. For current thread group, the thread
>   group identityHashcode is used; for individual threads, the thread
>   hashcode is used as the suffix.

**UPDATE 2012-02-09:**
Presume you have configuration as in comment below:

- N threads
- 1 CSV Data Set Config
- 1 csv data file
- N entries in csv data file

So you will get:

**1. N appearances** - in case of Sharing mode = "All threads" or "Current thread group": each thread will read 1 entry from csv: the 1st thread - the 1st entry, ..., the Nth thread - the Nth entry.

**2. N*N appearances** - in case of Sharing mode = "Current thread": each thread will read ALL the entries from csv.

Both the statements are for the case when CSV Data Set Config set with the following settings:

```
Recycle on EOF? = false
Stop thread on EOF? = false
```

(screenshot above).

Comment: Hi Alies,
Thanks for the reply...

Please look at this scenario....
I want to Search a google page for 5 threads.
I have 1 Dataset config and 1 CSV file having 5 values.
I select "All threads" option in the Sharing mode.
Then how many execution will occur ?
As said  : "the file is shared between all the threads."
It means each of the 5 threads will fetch all 5 values from CSV file and execute  the search....Means there would be 25 executions...

Correct me if I am wrong....Reply ASAP.....

Thank you,
Rishil Bhatt

Comment: @Rishil Bhatt
Please see update in answer above.
If you need 5 executions in your example - use "Current thread group" sharing mode.
If 25 executions - use "Current thread" one.

Comment: What is the Use of having multiple “CSV Dataset config” in a single test plan?

Comment: @Rishil Bhatt Please see screen for example above: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oRZJW.png. In this case all the thread groups are executed consequently. I use the _SINGLE_ csv-file with test-users credentials to initialize all the thread groups: so if I run N threads for TG-03 (in example) each thread will use unique credentials extracted from csv-file in CSV Dataset Config. TG-04 and TG-05 thread groups will use the same csv-file in the same manner. And since I use "Sharing Mode = Current thread group" option csv-file will be re-opened for each thread group and parsed from beginning.

Comment: @Rishil Bhatt You could better see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527769/jmeter-threads-using-dynamic-incremented-value/8538179#8538179) for more detailed explanation of the above case.